# jquery size guide - click, toggle functionality

Tags: jquery, onclick, toggle

I've been handed over some code to implement within a new domian, but I'm struggling to understand why the code is not initiating anything at all. I've tried debugging with alerts and console.logs but no luck. Any ideas  would be very welcome.

https://codepen.io/davidholloway/pen/BZQLwp

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // 'use strict';
    var sizeGuide = {
        isInit: false,
        init: function (options) {
            var optionsCopy = options || {},
                selector = optionsCopy.selector ? optionsCopy.selector : '.size_guide',
                $selector = $(selector),
                $guideWrappers = $selector.find('.guide_wrapper'),
                $guideCheckboxes = $selector.find('.guide_tgl--checkbox');

            // Global
            $guideWrappers.find('th.dual').hide();
            
            // All references tied to parent wrapper
            $selector.on('click', '.guide_update_trigger', function() {                
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.closest('ul').find('button').removeClass('guide_table--active_option').removeAttr('disabled');
                $this.addClass('guide_table--active_option').attr('disabled', true);
                $this.closest('.guide_wrapper').find('tbody th').toggle();
            });

            // Measurement unit switch
            $selector.on('click', '.guide_tgl--btn', function() {
                alert("hello");
                var $this = $(this),
                  imperialValues = $this.closest('.guide_wrapper').find('.imperial'),
                  metricValues = $this.closest('.guide_wrapper').find('.metric'),
                  imperialTooltip = $this.closest('.guide_wrapper').find('.tooltip.imperial'),
                  metricTooltip = $this.closest('.guide_wrapper').find('.tooltip.metric');

                if ($this.prev('.guide_tgl--checkbox').prop('checked') == false) {
                    $this.prev('.guide_tgl--checkbox').prop('checked', true);

                    metricValues.addClass('guide_unit--switchOut');
                    imperialValues.addClass('guide_unit--switchIn');

                    setTimeout(function(){ imperialValues.show().siblings('.metric').hide().removeClass('guide_unit--switchOut') }, 50);
                    setTimeout(function(){ imperialValues.removeClass('guide_unit--switchIn') }, 100);

                    imperialTooltip.show().removeClass('inactive_tooltip').addClass('active_tooltip');
                    metricTooltip.hide().removeClass('active_tooltip').addClass('inactive_tooltip');
                } else {
                    $this.prev('.guide_tgl--checkbox').prop('checked', false);

                    metricValues.addClass('guide_unit--switchIn');
                    imperialValues.addClass('guide_unit--switchOut');

                    setTimeout(function(){ metricValues.show().siblings('.imperial').hide().removeClass('guide_unit--switchOut'); }, 50);
                    setTimeout(function(){ metricValues.removeClass('guide_unit--switchIn') }, 100);

                    imperialTooltip.hide().removeClass('active_tooltip').addClass('inactive_tooltip');
                    metricTooltip.show().removeClass('inactive_tooltip').addClass('active_tooltip');
                }

                $this.siblings('h5.guide_tgl--label').toggleClass('guide_tgl--active_label');
            });

            sizeGuide.isInit = true;
        },
    }

    return sizeGuide;
    
});
```

```css
.size-guide-overlay .guide_wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 44px;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_wrapper:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #666;
    margin-top: 22px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_section {
    padding: 0 8px;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table thead tr {
    border-bottom: none;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table thead td, .size-guide-overlay .guide_table thead th {
    height: 48px;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table td {
    height: 40px;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table th {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table th, .size-guide-overlay .guide_table thead {
    background: #F8F7F6;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table th .guide_unit--switchIn, .size-guide-overlay .guide_table th .guide_unit--switchOut {
    color: #F8F7F6;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table th.imperial+th, .size-guide-overlay .guide_table th.metric+th {
    border-right: 2px solid #FFF;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table th+th {
    border-right: none;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table th.dual:after, .size-guide-overlay .guide_table th.single:after, .size-guide-overlay .guide_table th.single:before {
    content: '';
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table span {
    font-size: 10px;
}
.size-guide-overlay h3 {
    clear: both;
}
.size-guide-overlay .imperial {
    display: none;
}
.size-guide-overlay .imperial:before, .size-guide-overlay .metric:before {
    padding-left: 0;
    content: ''}
.size-guide-overlay .imperial:after, .size-guide-overlay .metric:after {
    padding-right: 0;
    content: ''}
.size-guide-overlay td.guide_unit--switchOut {
    color: #fff;
    transform: translateX(60px);
}
.size-guide-overlay td.guide_unit--switchIn {
    color: #fff;
    transform: translateX(-60px);
}
.size-guide-overlay th.guide_unit--switchIn, .size-guide-overlay th.guide_unit--switchOut {
    color: #F8F7F6;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_unit--switchIn:after, .size-guide-overlay .guide_unit--switchOut:before {
    content: ''}
.size-guide-overlay th.guide_unit--switchOut:before {
    padding-left: 60px;
    content: '';
    transition: all .2s ease;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.size-guide-overlay th.guide_unit--switchIn:after {
    padding-right: 60px;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_a td {
    width: 25%}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_a--alt td {
    width: 20%}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_a--alt td:first-child {
    color: #999;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_a--alt td:first-child+td {
    color: #333;
    width: 0;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_b td {
    width: 33.33%}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_b1 td {
    width: 25%}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_b2 td {
    width: 50%}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_b2 tr:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_b2 tr:first-child th {
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_c_form {
    float: left;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_c_form--selection {
    width: 284px;
    height: 44px;
    border-radius: 4px!important;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background: #fff;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_c_form label {
    display: block;
    width: 284px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 0;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_c_form select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_c_form option {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_c_form div {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_c td {
    width: 25%}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table--loader {
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    border-top: 6px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 6px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 6px solid #666;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-animation: load8 .8s infinite linear;
    animation: load8 .8s infinite linear;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table--loader, .size-guide-overlay .guide_table--loader:after {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load8 {
    0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}@keyframes load8 {
    0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}.size-guide-overlay .table_type_d td {
    width: 25%}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_d th, .size-guide-overlay .table_type_d1 th {
    color: #333;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_d1 td {
    width: 16.66%}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_tgl, .size-guide-overlay .guide_tgl--label {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    display: inline;
    transition: color .2s ease;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_tgl--active_label {
    color: #333;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_tgl--btn {
    width: 48px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 12px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    margin: 0 10px -5px;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_tgl--checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_tgl--checkbox+span.guide_tgl--btn:after {
    background-color: #666;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    width: 20px;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_tgl--checkbox:checked+span.guide_tgl--btn:after {
    left: 26px;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table--metric {
    display: none;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table--imperial {
    display: table;
}
.size-guide-overlay ul.guide_table--options {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    clear: both;
}
.size-guide-overlay ul.guide_table--options li {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.size-guide-overlay ul.guide_table--options li button.guide_table--active_option {
    color: #666;
    border-bottom-color: #666;
}
.size-guide-overlay ul.guide_table--options li button {
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top: 0 solid #fff;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #00539F;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Tesco, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 800;
    height: 100%;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transition: border-bottom-color .2s ease;
    width: 100%}
.size-guide-overlay ul.guide_table--options li button:hover {
    border-width: 0;
    color: #4A90E2;
}
.size-guide-overlay ul.guide_table--options li button:disabled:hover {
    color: #666;
    background: #fff;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #666;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_tgl--heading {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 20px 0 12px;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_section h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #00539F;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 100;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: none;
}
.size-guide-overlay .info_overflow:after {
    content: '!';
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    left: 0;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow .tooltip:after, .size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow .tooltip:before {
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    content: '';
    left: 37px;
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow:hover {
    background-color: #008DC8;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow .tooltip:before {
    border-top: 20px solid #ccc;
    bottom: -20px;
    transition: none;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow .tooltip:after {
    border-top: 20px solid #f6f6f6;
    bottom: -19px;
}
.size-guide-overlay span.tooltip {
    display: inline-block!important;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: -50px;
    width: 110px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border: thin solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    font-size: 14px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .15s ease;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #333!important;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow:hover span.tooltip {
    top: -60px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .15s ease;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow span.tooltip.metric {
    visibility: visible;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow span.tooltip.imperial {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow:hover span.tooltip.active_tooltip {
    visibility: visible;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow:hover span.tooltip.inactive_tooltip {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="../size-guide.css" />

<div class="size-guide-overlay">
<div class="size_guide">
<section class="guide_section">
  <!--<h2>Boys' size guide</h2>
  <p>Welcome to our size guide for F&amp;F clothing. Please note that the guide here applies to F&amp;F collections only, as the sizing of branded collections may be slightly different.<br><br> When measuring, make sure that your child's feet are flat on the floor and keep the tape measure level around the body.<br><br></p>
<h3>F&amp;F BOYS' SIZE CHARTS</h3>-->
<div class="guide_wrapper">

<ul class="guide_table--options">
<li><button class="guide_update_trigger guide_table--active_option" disabled>Single Sizes</button></li>
<li><button class="guide_update_trigger">Dual Sizes</button></li>
</ul>
<h4 class="guide_tgl--heading">Show dimensions as:</h4>
<div class="guide_tgl">
<h5 class="guide_tgl--label guide_tgl--active_label">CENTIMETRES</h5>
<input class="guide_tgl--checkbox" type="checkbox">
<span class="guide_tgl--btn"></span>
<h5 class="guide_tgl--label">INCHES</h5>
</div>

<table class="guide_table table_type_b">
<thead>
<tr style="width: 100%;">
<th>Age</th>
<th>Height</th>
<th>Weight<span class="metric"> (kg)</span><span class="imperial"> (lbs)</span></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="single">Tiny baby</th>
<th class="dual">Tiny baby</th>
<td class="metric">44</td>
<td class="metric">2.25</td>
<td class="imperial">17<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">Newborn</th>
<th class="dual">Newborn</th>
<td class="metric">50</td>
<td class="metric">3.4</td>
<td class="imperial">19<span>3/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">7<span>1/2</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">Up to 1 mth</th>
<th class="dual">Up to 1 mth</th>
<td class="metric">56</td>
<td class="metric">4.5</td>
<td class="imperial">22</td>
<td class="imperial">10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">Up to 3 mths</th>
<th class="dual">0 - 3 mths</th>
<td class="metric">62</td>
<td class="metric">6.5</td>
<td class="imperial">24<span>1/2</span></td>
<td class="imperial">14<span>1/2</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">6 mths</th>
<th class="dual">3 - 6 mths or 0 - 6 mths</th>
<td class="metric">68</td>
<td class="metric">8</td>
<td class="imperial">26<span>3/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">9 mths</th>
<th class="dual">6 - 9 mths</th>
<td class="metric">74</td>
<td class="metric">9</td>
<td class="imperial">29</td>
<td class="imperial">20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">12 mths</th>
<th class="dual">9 - 12 mths</th>
<td class="metric">80</td>
<td class="metric">11</td>
<td class="imperial">31<span>1/2</span></td>
<td class="imperial">24</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">18 mths</th>
<th class="dual">12 - 18 mths</th>
<td class="metric">86</td>
<td class="metric">12.5</td>
<td class="imperial">33<span>7/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">28</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>


<div class="guide_wrapper">
<ul class="guide_table--options">
<li><button class="guide_update_trigger guide_table--active_option" disabled>Single Sizes</button></li>
<li><button class="guide_update_trigger">Dual Sizes</button></li>
</ul>
<h4 class="guide_tgl--heading">Show dimensions as:</h4>
<div class="guide_tgl">
<h5 class="guide_tgl--label guide_tgl--active_label">CENTIMETRES</h5>
<input class="guide_tgl--checkbox" type="checkbox">
<span class="guide_tgl--btn"></span>
<h5 class="guide_tgl--label">INCHES</h5>
</div>

<table class="guide_table table_type_a--alt">
<thead>
<tr style="width: 100%;">
<th>Age</th>
<th>Height</th>
<th>Collar</th>
<th>Chest</th>
<th>Waist</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="single">24 mths</th>
<th class="dual">18 - 24 mths</th>
<td class="metric">92</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">52.5</td>
<td class="metric">50.5</td>
<td class="imperial">36<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">20<span>5/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">19<span>7/8</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">3 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">2 - 3 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">98</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">54</td>
<td class="metric">52.5</td>
<td class="imperial">38<span>5/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">21<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">20<span>5/8</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">4 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">3 - 4 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">104</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">56</td>
<td class="metric">54.5</td>
<td class="imperial">40<span>7/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">22<span>1/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">21<span>1/2</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">5 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">4 - 5 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">110</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">58</td>
<td class="metric">55</td>
<td class="imperial">43<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">22<span>7/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">21<span>5/8</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">6 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">5 - 6 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">116</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">60.5</td>
<td class="metric">56</td>
<td class="imperial">45<span>5/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">23<span>3/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">22</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">7 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">6 - 7 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">122</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">63</td>
<td class="metric">57</td>
<td class="imperial">48<span>1/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">24<span>3/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">22<span>1/2</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">8 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">7 - 8 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">128</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">64</td>
<td class="metric">59</td>
<td class="imperial">50<span>3/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">25<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">23<span>1/4</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">9 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">8 - 9 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">134</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">67.5</td>
<td class="metric">61.5</td>
<td class="imperial">52<span>3/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">26<span>1/2</span></td>
<td class="imperial">24<span>1/4</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">10 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">9 - 10 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">140</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">71</td>
<td class="metric">63.5</td>
<td class="imperial">55<span>1/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">28</td>
<td class="imperial">25</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>


<div class="guide_wrapper">
<ul class="guide_table--options">
<li><button class="guide_update_trigger guide_table--active_option" disabled>Single Sizes</button></li>
<li><button class="guide_update_trigger">Dual Sizes</button></li>
</ul>
<h4 class="guide_tgl--heading">Show dimensions as:</h4>
<div class="guide_tgl">
<h5 class="guide_tgl--label guide_tgl--active_label">CENTIMETRES</h5>
<input class="guide_tgl--checkbox" type="checkbox">
<span class="guide_tgl--btn"></span>
<h5 class="guide_tgl--label">INCHES</h5>
</div>

<table class="guide_table table_type_d1">
<thead>
<tr style="width: 100%;">
<th>Age</th>
<th>Height</th>
<th>Collar</th>
<th>Chest</th>
<th>Waist</th>
<th>Inside Leg</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="single">11 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">10-11 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">146</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">74.5</td>
<td class="metric">66</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="imperial">57<span>1/2</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">29<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">26</td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">12 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">11 - 12 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">152</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">78</td>
<td class="metric">68</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="imperial">59<span>7/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">30<span>3/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">26<span>3/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">13 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">12 - 13 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">158</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">82</td>
<td class="metric">71.5</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="imperial">62<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">32<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">28<span>1/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">14 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">13 - 14 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">164</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">86</td>
<td class="metric">75</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="imperial">64<span>5/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">33<span>7/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">29<span>1/2</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">15 yrs <div class="info_overflow">
<span class="tooltip metric">Inside leg: 78</span>
<span class="tooltip imperial">Inside leg: 30<span>3/4</span></span>
</div></th>
<th class="dual">14 - 15 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">170</td>
<td class="metric">35.75</td>
<td class="metric">89</td>
<td class="metric">77.5</td>
<td class="metric">78</td>
<td class="imperial">67</td>
<td class="imperial">14<span>1/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">35</td>
<td class="imperial">30<span>1/2</span></td>
<td class="imperial">30<span>3/4</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">16 yrs <div class="info_overflow">
<span class="tooltip metric">Inside leg: 82</span>
<span class="tooltip imperial">Inside leg: 32<span>1/4</span></span>
</div></th>
<th class="dual">15 - 16 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">176</td>
<td class="metric">37</td>
<td class="metric">91.5</td>
<td class="metric">80</td>
<td class="metric">82</td>
<td class="imperial">69<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">15<span>1/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">36</td>
<td class="imperial">31<span>1/2</span></td>
<td class="imperial">32<span>1/4</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>


<div class="guide_wrapper">
<h4 class="guide_tgl--heading">Show dimensions as:</h4>
<div class="guide_tgl">
<h5 class="guide_tgl--label guide_tgl--active_label">CENTIMETRES</h5>
<input class="guide_tgl--checkbox" type="checkbox">
<span class="guide_tgl--btn"></span>
<h5 class="guide_tgl--label">INCHES</h5>
</div>

<table class="guide_table table_type_b">
<thead>
<tr style="width: 100%;">
<th>Size</th>
<th>Height</th>
<th>Chest</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>S</th>
<td class="metric">122</td>
<td class="metric">63</td>
<td class="imperial">48<span>1/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">25</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>M</th>
<td class="metric">140</td>
<td class="metric">71</td>
<td class="imperial">55<span>1/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>L</th>
<td class="metric">158</td>
<td class="metric">88</td>
<td class="imperial">62<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">32<span>1/4</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>XL</th>
<td class="metric">176</td>
<td class="metric">91.5</td>
<td class="imperial">69<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">36</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</section>
<!-- Boys Section End -->




</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the script part

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // 'use strict';
        /*isInit: false,
        init:*/ 
var sizeGuide = 
        function (options) {
            var optionsCopy = options || {},
                selector = optionsCopy.selector ? optionsCopy.selector : '.size_guide',
                $selector = $(selector),
                $guideWrappers = $selector.find('.guide_wrapper'),
                $guideCheckboxes = $selector.find('.guide_tgl--checkbox');

            // Global
            $guideWrappers.find('th.dual').hide();
            
            // All references tied to parent wrapper
            $selector.on('click', '.guide_update_trigger', function() {                
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.closest('ul').find('button').removeClass('guide_table--active_option').removeAttr('disabled');
                $this.addClass('guide_table--active_option').attr('disabled', true);
                $this.closest('.guide_wrapper').find('tbody th').toggle();
            });

            // Measurement unit switch
            $selector.on('click', '.guide_tgl--btn', function() {
                alert("hello");
                var $this = $(this),
                  imperialValues = $this.closest('.guide_wrapper').find('.imperial'),
                  metricValues = $this.closest('.guide_wrapper').find('.metric'),
                  imperialTooltip = $this.closest('.guide_wrapper').find('.tooltip.imperial'),
                  metricTooltip = $this.closest('.guide_wrapper').find('.tooltip.metric');

                if ($this.prev('.guide_tgl--checkbox').prop('checked') == false) {
                    $this.prev('.guide_tgl--checkbox').prop('checked', true);

                    metricValues.addClass('guide_unit--switchOut');
                    imperialValues.addClass('guide_unit--switchIn');

                    setTimeout(function(){ imperialValues.show().siblings('.metric').hide().removeClass('guide_unit--switchOut') }, 50);
                    setTimeout(function(){ imperialValues.removeClass('guide_unit--switchIn') }, 100);

                    imperialTooltip.show().removeClass('inactive_tooltip').addClass('active_tooltip');
                    metricTooltip.hide().removeClass('active_tooltip').addClass('inactive_tooltip');
                } else {
                    $this.prev('.guide_tgl--checkbox').prop('checked', false);

                    metricValues.addClass('guide_unit--switchIn');
                    imperialValues.addClass('guide_unit--switchOut');

                    setTimeout(function(){ metricValues.show().siblings('.imperial').hide().removeClass('guide_unit--switchOut'); }, 50);
                    setTimeout(function(){ metricValues.removeClass('guide_unit--switchIn') }, 100);

                    imperialTooltip.hide().removeClass('active_tooltip').addClass('inactive_tooltip');
                    metricTooltip.show().removeClass('inactive_tooltip').addClass('active_tooltip');
                }

                $this.siblings('h5.guide_tgl--label').toggleClass('guide_tgl--active_label');
            });

            sizeGuide.isInit = true;
        }
        sizeGuide();
    
});
```

```css
 .size-guide-overlay .guide_wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 44px;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_wrapper:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #666;
    margin-top: 22px;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_section {
    padding: 0 8px;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table tr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table thead tr {
    border-bottom: none;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table thead td, .size-guide-overlay .guide_table thead th {
    height: 48px;
    font-weight: 800;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table td {
    height: 40px;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table th {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table th, .size-guide-overlay .guide_table thead {
    background: #F8F7F6;
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table th .guide_unit--switchIn, .size-guide-overlay .guide_table th .guide_unit--switchOut {
    color: #F8F7F6;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table th.imperial+th, .size-guide-overlay .guide_table th.metric+th {
    border-right: 2px solid #FFF;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table th+th {
    border-right: none;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table th.dual:after, .size-guide-overlay .guide_table th.single:after, .size-guide-overlay .guide_table th.single:before {
    content: '';
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table span {
    font-size: 10px;
}
.size-guide-overlay h3 {
    clear: both;
}
.size-guide-overlay .imperial {
    display: none;
}
.size-guide-overlay .imperial:before, .size-guide-overlay .metric:before {
    padding-left: 0;
    content: ''}
.size-guide-overlay .imperial:after, .size-guide-overlay .metric:after {
    padding-right: 0;
    content: ''}
.size-guide-overlay td.guide_unit--switchOut {
    color: #fff;
    transform: translateX(60px);
}
.size-guide-overlay td.guide_unit--switchIn {
    color: #fff;
    transform: translateX(-60px);
}
.size-guide-overlay th.guide_unit--switchIn, .size-guide-overlay th.guide_unit--switchOut {
    color: #F8F7F6;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_unit--switchIn:after, .size-guide-overlay .guide_unit--switchOut:before {
    content: ''}
.size-guide-overlay th.guide_unit--switchOut:before {
    padding-left: 60px;
    content: '';
    transition: all .2s ease;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.size-guide-overlay th.guide_unit--switchIn:after {
    padding-right: 60px;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_a td {
    width: 25%}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_a--alt td {
    width: 20%}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_a--alt td:first-child {
    color: #999;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_a--alt td:first-child+td {
    color: #333;
    width: 0;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_b td {
    width: 33.33%}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_b1 td {
    width: 25%}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_b2 td {
    width: 50%}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_b2 tr:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_b2 tr:first-child th {
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_c_form {
    float: left;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_c_form--selection {
    width: 284px;
    height: 44px;
    border-radius: 4px!important;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background: #fff;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_c_form label {
    display: block;
    width: 284px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 0;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_c_form select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_c_form option {
    padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_c_form div {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_c td {
    width: 25%}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table--loader {
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    border-top: 6px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 6px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 6px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 6px solid #666;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-animation: load8 .8s infinite linear;
    animation: load8 .8s infinite linear;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table--loader, .size-guide-overlay .guide_table--loader:after {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 44px;
    height: 44px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes load8 {
    0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}@keyframes load8 {
    0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
}
100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
}.size-guide-overlay .table_type_d td {
    width: 25%}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_d th, .size-guide-overlay .table_type_d1 th {
    color: #333;
}
.size-guide-overlay .table_type_d1 td {
    width: 16.66%}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_tgl, .size-guide-overlay .guide_tgl--label {
    color: #999;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    display: inline;
    transition: color .2s ease;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_tgl--active_label {
    color: #333;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_tgl--btn {
    width: 48px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 12px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    margin: 0 10px -5px;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_tgl--checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_tgl--checkbox+span.guide_tgl--btn:after {
    background-color: #666;
    border-radius: 50%;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    transition: all .2s ease;
    width: 20px;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_tgl--checkbox:checked+span.guide_tgl--btn:after {
    left: 26px;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table--metric {
    display: none;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table--imperial {
    display: table;
}
.size-guide-overlay ul.guide_table--options {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    clear: both;
}
.size-guide-overlay ul.guide_table--options li {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.size-guide-overlay ul.guide_table--options li button.guide_table--active_option {
    color: #666;
    border-bottom-color: #666;
}
.size-guide-overlay ul.guide_table--options li button {
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top: 0 solid #fff;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #00539F;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Tesco, Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 800;
    height: 100%;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    transition: border-bottom-color .2s ease;
    width: 100%}
.size-guide-overlay ul.guide_table--options li button:hover {
    border-width: 0;
    color: #4A90E2;
}
.size-guide-overlay ul.guide_table--options li button:disabled:hover {
    color: #666;
    background: #fff;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #666;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_tgl--heading {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 20px 0 12px;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_section h3 {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #00539F;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    z-index: 100;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: none;
}
.size-guide-overlay .info_overflow:after {
    content: '!';
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    left: 0;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow .tooltip:after, .size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow .tooltip:before {
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    content: '';
    left: 37px;
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow:hover {
    background-color: #008DC8;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow .tooltip:before {
    border-top: 20px solid #ccc;
    bottom: -20px;
    transition: none;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow .tooltip:after {
    border-top: 20px solid #f6f6f6;
    bottom: -19px;
}
.size-guide-overlay span.tooltip {
    display: inline-block!important;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: -50px;
    width: 110px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    border: thin solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #f6f6f6;
    font-size: 14px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .15s ease;
    pointer-events: none;
    color: #333!important;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow:hover span.tooltip {
    top: -60px;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .15s ease;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow span.tooltip.metric {
    visibility: visible;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow span.tooltip.imperial {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow:hover span.tooltip.active_tooltip {
    visibility: visible;
}
.size-guide-overlay .guide_table .info_overflow:hover span.tooltip.inactive_tooltip {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="../size-guide.css" /> -->

<div class="size-guide-overlay">
<div class="size_guide">
<section class="guide_section">
  <!--<h2>Boys' size guide</h2>
  <p>Welcome to our size guide for F&amp;F clothing. Please note that the guide here applies to F&amp;F collections only, as the sizing of branded collections may be slightly different.<br><br> When measuring, make sure that your child's feet are flat on the floor and keep the tape measure level around the body.<br><br></p>
<h3>F&amp;F BOYS' SIZE CHARTS</h3>-->
<div class="guide_wrapper">

<ul class="guide_table--options">
<li><button class="guide_update_trigger guide_table--active_option" disabled>Single Sizes</button></li>
<li><button class="guide_update_trigger">Dual Sizes</button></li>
</ul>
<h4 class="guide_tgl--heading">Show dimensions as:</h4>
<div class="guide_tgl">
<h5 class="guide_tgl--label guide_tgl--active_label">CENTIMETRES</h5>
<input class="guide_tgl--checkbox" type="checkbox">
<span class="guide_tgl--btn"></span>
<h5 class="guide_tgl--label">INCHES</h5>
</div>

<table class="guide_table table_type_b">
<thead>
<tr style="width: 100%;">
<th>Age</th>
<th>Height</th>
<th>Weight<span class="metric"> (kg)</span><span class="imperial"> (lbs)</span></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="single">Tiny baby</th>
<th class="dual">Tiny baby</th>
<td class="metric">44</td>
<td class="metric">2.25</td>
<td class="imperial">17<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">Newborn</th>
<th class="dual">Newborn</th>
<td class="metric">50</td>
<td class="metric">3.4</td>
<td class="imperial">19<span>3/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">7<span>1/2</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">Up to 1 mth</th>
<th class="dual">Up to 1 mth</th>
<td class="metric">56</td>
<td class="metric">4.5</td>
<td class="imperial">22</td>
<td class="imperial">10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">Up to 3 mths</th>
<th class="dual">0 - 3 mths</th>
<td class="metric">62</td>
<td class="metric">6.5</td>
<td class="imperial">24<span>1/2</span></td>
<td class="imperial">14<span>1/2</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">6 mths</th>
<th class="dual">3 - 6 mths or 0 - 6 mths</th>
<td class="metric">68</td>
<td class="metric">8</td>
<td class="imperial">26<span>3/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">18</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">9 mths</th>
<th class="dual">6 - 9 mths</th>
<td class="metric">74</td>
<td class="metric">9</td>
<td class="imperial">29</td>
<td class="imperial">20</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">12 mths</th>
<th class="dual">9 - 12 mths</th>
<td class="metric">80</td>
<td class="metric">11</td>
<td class="imperial">31<span>1/2</span></td>
<td class="imperial">24</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">18 mths</th>
<th class="dual">12 - 18 mths</th>
<td class="metric">86</td>
<td class="metric">12.5</td>
<td class="imperial">33<span>7/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">28</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>


<div class="guide_wrapper">
<ul class="guide_table--options">
<li><button class="guide_update_trigger guide_table--active_option" disabled>Single Sizes</button></li>
<li><button class="guide_update_trigger">Dual Sizes</button></li>
</ul>
<h4 class="guide_tgl--heading">Show dimensions as:</h4>
<div class="guide_tgl">
<h5 class="guide_tgl--label guide_tgl--active_label">CENTIMETRES</h5>
<input class="guide_tgl--checkbox" type="checkbox">
<span class="guide_tgl--btn"></span>
<h5 class="guide_tgl--label">INCHES</h5>
</div>

<table class="guide_table table_type_a--alt">
<thead>
<tr style="width: 100%;">
<th>Age</th>
<th>Height</th>
<th>Collar</th>
<th>Chest</th>
<th>Waist</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="single">24 mths</th>
<th class="dual">18 - 24 mths</th>
<td class="metric">92</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">52.5</td>
<td class="metric">50.5</td>
<td class="imperial">36<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">20<span>5/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">19<span>7/8</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">3 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">2 - 3 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">98</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">54</td>
<td class="metric">52.5</td>
<td class="imperial">38<span>5/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">21<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">20<span>5/8</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">4 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">3 - 4 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">104</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">56</td>
<td class="metric">54.5</td>
<td class="imperial">40<span>7/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">22<span>1/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">21<span>1/2</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">5 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">4 - 5 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">110</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">58</td>
<td class="metric">55</td>
<td class="imperial">43<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">22<span>7/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">21<span>5/8</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">6 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">5 - 6 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">116</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">60.5</td>
<td class="metric">56</td>
<td class="imperial">45<span>5/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">23<span>3/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">22</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">7 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">6 - 7 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">122</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">63</td>
<td class="metric">57</td>
<td class="imperial">48<span>1/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">24<span>3/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">22<span>1/2</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">8 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">7 - 8 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">128</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">64</td>
<td class="metric">59</td>
<td class="imperial">50<span>3/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">25<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">23<span>1/4</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">9 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">8 - 9 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">134</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">67.5</td>
<td class="metric">61.5</td>
<td class="imperial">52<span>3/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">26<span>1/2</span></td>
<td class="imperial">24<span>1/4</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">10 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">9 - 10 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">140</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">71</td>
<td class="metric">63.5</td>
<td class="imperial">55<span>1/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">28</td>
<td class="imperial">25</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>


<div class="guide_wrapper">
<ul class="guide_table--options">
<li><button class="guide_update_trigger guide_table--active_option" disabled>Single Sizes</button></li>
<li><button class="guide_update_trigger">Dual Sizes</button></li>
</ul>
<h4 class="guide_tgl--heading">Show dimensions as:</h4>
<div class="guide_tgl">
<h5 class="guide_tgl--label guide_tgl--active_label">CENTIMETRES</h5>
<input class="guide_tgl--checkbox" type="checkbox">
<span class="guide_tgl--btn"></span>
<h5 class="guide_tgl--label">INCHES</h5>
</div>

<table class="guide_table table_type_d1">
<thead>
<tr style="width: 100%;">
<th>Age</th>
<th>Height</th>
<th>Collar</th>
<th>Chest</th>
<th>Waist</th>
<th>Inside Leg</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="single">11 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">10-11 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">146</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">74.5</td>
<td class="metric">66</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="imperial">57<span>1/2</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">29<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">26</td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">12 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">11 - 12 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">152</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">78</td>
<td class="metric">68</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="imperial">59<span>7/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">30<span>3/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">26<span>3/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">13 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">12 - 13 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">158</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">82</td>
<td class="metric">71.5</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="imperial">62<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">32<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">28<span>1/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">14 yrs</th>
<th class="dual">13 - 14 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">164</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="metric">86</td>
<td class="metric">75</td>
<td class="metric">-</td>
<td class="imperial">64<span>5/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
<td class="imperial">33<span>7/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">29<span>1/2</span></td>
<td class="imperial">-</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">15 yrs <div class="info_overflow">
<span class="tooltip metric">Inside leg: 78</span>
<span class="tooltip imperial">Inside leg: 30<span>3/4</span></span>
</div></th>
<th class="dual">14 - 15 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">170</td>
<td class="metric">35.75</td>
<td class="metric">89</td>
<td class="metric">77.5</td>
<td class="metric">78</td>
<td class="imperial">67</td>
<td class="imperial">14<span>1/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">35</td>
<td class="imperial">30<span>1/2</span></td>
<td class="imperial">30<span>3/4</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="single">16 yrs <div class="info_overflow">
<span class="tooltip metric">Inside leg: 82</span>
<span class="tooltip imperial">Inside leg: 32<span>1/4</span></span>
</div></th>
<th class="dual">15 - 16 yrs</th>
<td class="metric">176</td>
<td class="metric">37</td>
<td class="metric">91.5</td>
<td class="metric">80</td>
<td class="metric">82</td>
<td class="imperial">69<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">15<span>1/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">36</td>
<td class="imperial">31<span>1/2</span></td>
<td class="imperial">32<span>1/4</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>


<div class="guide_wrapper">
<h4 class="guide_tgl--heading">Show dimensions as:</h4>
<div class="guide_tgl">
<h5 class="guide_tgl--label guide_tgl--active_label">CENTIMETRES</h5>
<input class="guide_tgl--checkbox" type="checkbox">
<span class="guide_tgl--btn"></span>
<h5 class="guide_tgl--label">INCHES</h5>
</div>

<table class="guide_table table_type_b">
<thead>
<tr style="width: 100%;">
<th>Size</th>
<th>Height</th>
<th>Chest</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>S</th>
<td class="metric">122</td>
<td class="metric">63</td>
<td class="imperial">48<span>1/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">25</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>M</th>
<td class="metric">140</td>
<td class="metric">71</td>
<td class="imperial">55<span>1/8</span></td>
<td class="imperial">28</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>L</th>
<td class="metric">158</td>
<td class="metric">88</td>
<td class="imperial">62<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">32<span>1/4</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>XL</th>
<td class="metric">176</td>
<td class="metric">91.5</td>
<td class="imperial">69<span>1/4</span></td>
<td class="imperial">36</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</section>
<!-- Boys Section End -->




</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Nidchin, I can see from the script that the function was part of a broader set of code and was originally getting initiated elsewhere? thanks